# Code coverage for wrapper class is 0%

Tags: apex, code-coverage

I have written below Wrapper class.

```
global class BI_VA_AutomationWrapper {    

global class BI_VA_AutomationRequest {

    webservice String userName;
    webservice String emailId;
    webservice String buinessUnit;
    webservice String orgName;
    webservice String country;
    webservice String environment;
    webservice String myShopNumber;
    webservice String BidsId;//for testing
    webservice String Type; //for testing

}

global class BI_VA_AutomationResponse {

    webservice String responseStatus;
    webservice String myShopNumber;
    //webservice list<Error> errorMessages;
    webservice String  errorMessages;//for testing 

}
global class BI_VA_Error {

    webservice String type;
    webservice String message;   
}}
```

And test class is,

```
@isTest
public class BI_VA_AutomationWrapperTestClass 
{
public static testMethod void unitTest(){

    BI_VA_AutomationWrapper.BI_VA_AutomationRequest wrap= new BI_VA_AutomationWrapper.BI_VA_AutomationRequest();   
    wrap.userName='Test@test.com';
    wrap.emailId='Test@test11.com';
    wrap.buinessUnit='AH';
    wrap.orgName='ORD';
    wrap.country='US';
    wrap.environment='QA';
    wrap.myShopNumber='123456789';
    wrap.BidsId='123';
    wrap.Type='ResetPassword';        

    BI_VA_AutomationWrapper.BI_VA_AutomationResponse res= new BI_VA_AutomationWrapper.BI_VA_AutomationResponse();
    res.responseStatus = 'Success';
    res.myShopNumber = '987654321';
    res.errorMessages = 'Test error';

    BI_VA_AutomationWrapper.BI_VA_Error error = new BI_VA_AutomationWrapper.BI_VA_Error();
    error.type = 'Test';
    error.message = 'Test';

}}
```

Code coverage is 0% only.

Comment: What error did you get when you ran the test class?

Answer (score 4):

Your wrapper class contains no executable lines of code (only variable declarations). As such, it cannot be covered in a test class and will always show 0% coverage. Non-executable lines of code do not count in the [code coverage metrics](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_code_coverage_intro.htm):

> Code coverage percentage is a calculation of the number of covered lines divided by the sum of the number of covered lines and uncovered lines. Only executable lines of code are included

While variable declarations are represented as covered when they're in an executable method body, instance variables are not.

Comment: i would add that marking a { get; set; } at the end of the block would give that some coverage since those essentially are methods. That is, if he wanted to see his lines covered.

Comment: You're right; adding a property declaration will obtain coverage. I'd argue against doing this, though. There's no need to cover those lines *per se*, and adding property declarations just adds bytes and lines of code to cover for no real reason.

Comment: No argument there, just wanted to additionally point out the difference for other users.